# API Gateway: JSON 5+ MB Gives error "413, Request Too Long"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have sample json which is more than 5MB,

When not using lambda integration & try to do post request

```
413 Request Too Long
```

If I use lambda integration it gives

```
502 Internal server error
```

Request does not reach to my lambda function

In response headers I'm getting following error:

```
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
```

If I use mock service it works & gives 200 response.

As per [Api documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) it supports max 10MB.

I want to get this json in my request.

Any solutions?

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @KingAndrew For our case we used pre-signed URL of S3 bucket and then used lambda function to process it.

Comment: Thanks, @JagsSparrow we are going that way as well.  The only thing that concerns me of this approach is the lack of status response back to the client.  I don't suppose you have a way to notify the client there was an error in your lambda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is not the limit of the API Gateway, but rather the request limit of the Lambda function. Those have a limit of 6MB for the whole input. So depending on you input mapping 5+MB payload could result in a larger payload for the Lambda request.

[AWS Lambda Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)